# Message dialog boxes in a computer guessing game

Tags: java, user-interface, dialog, joptionpane

Hello I am making a game and I'm trying to program it so the user is thinking of a random number and the program tries to guess it. I have to use message dialog boxes (it's a school project) and it asks the user if the number is too high, too low, or correct, but when the number is too low, it guesses numbers that are higher. What is the issue? (Assume count has been initialized as 0.)

```
boolean correctGuess = false; // when computer guesses incorrectly, correctGuess is false

String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Is " + progNum + " too high, too low, or correct?", " ");


while(correctGuess == false)   // when the computer is guessing
{

if(n.equals("correct"))  // if the number is correct 
{
  count++;     // update number of guesses
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yay! " + progNum + " was correct! It took the computer " + count + " guesses."); // correct guess, displays number of guesses
  correctGuess= true;  // computer guessed the correct number
  break;  // program stops
}
else if(n.equals("too high")) // number is too high, prog generates lower number
{
  count++;      // update number of guesses
  int max = (progNum - 1);        // guess was too high so progNum-1 is the max
  int min = 1;        // min value is progNum + 1 since progNum is too high
  progNum = generator.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;      // new range for progNum between 1 and progNum1 - 1
  String tooHigh = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Is " + progNum + " too high, too low, or correct?", " "); // asks user

  if (tooHigh == null)
   return;

 }
else if(n.equals("too low")) // number is too low, prog generates higher number
{
  count++;          // update number of guesses
  int max = 100;     // generate a range of values for another random guess
  int min = (progNum + 1);      // min value is progNum + 1 since progNum is too low
  progNum = generator.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;      // new range for progNum between 1 and progNum1 + 1
  String tooLow = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Is " + progNum + " too high, too low, or correct?", " ");  // asks user

  if (tooLow == null)
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never update n. Insiede the while loop, when you ask if it is too high or too low, you store the user's answer in another variable. You need to store the users answer in n, like you did in the beginning.

Comment: How do I store user's answers in n?

Comment: Try: n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Is " + progNum + " too high, too low, or correct?", " "); instead of using the vaeriables tooLow or tooHigh

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes would likely make this a bit easier to follow. The basic issue, I think, is that you have a check for "n" in the loop, but you re-collect the result in the `if` statements.

You can move the count increase out of the individual `if` statements, and allow the collection of the response to happen within the loop.

```
int min = 0;
int max = 100;

// loop while an incorrect guess
while (! correctGuess) {
  // do a binary search
  //  max and min are updated on each check
  int progNum = ((max - min) / 2) + min;

  // collect the response
  String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Is " + progNum + " too high, too low, or correct?", " ");

  // cancel by user
  if (n == null) {
    break;
  }      

  // user made a guess
  ++count;

  if (n.equals("correct")) {
    OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yay! " + progNum + " was correct! It took the computer " + count + " guesses."); // correct guess, displays number of guesses
    correctGuess= true;  // computer guessed the correct number
    continue;  // program stops
  }
  else if (n.equals("too high")) {
    max = progNum - 1;
  }
  else if (n.equals("too low")) {
    min = progNum + 1;
  }
}
```

Edit: you may wish to look closely at the way the next guess number is generated. I would think a pure binary search approach would be more effective than choosing a random number within a range.

Edit 2: You can see the basic binary search approach [at this link here](https://ideone.com/jAByir).